# How attach document.click event without touching some element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I need to click on a document to call some function, but the problem is that when I click on some element that want it doesnt react, so the code:

```
<body>

<div class="some_element">
some element
</div>



</body>
```

and js:

```
$(document).click(function(){

   //something to happen

})
```

and now if I click on the div with `class="some_element"` the `document.click` event will be called, but I need to call that event ONLY when I click on the document; or it is possible the make this element an exception?

More detailed:

```
$('#forma').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    
    $('#assignment_type_list').slideUp();


})
```

Lets say `#forma` - its a parent element of those element, so when I click on the page I want to slideUp someElement and:

```
$('#assignment_type_select, #assignment_type_label').click(function(){
    
        $('#assignment_type_list').slideToggle();
            
            })
```

this is the elements when they are clicked the other element is toggled, but the problem is that when I click on this elements the `$('#forma').click` - also executes, because its parent and the `e.stopPropagation()` - doesn't help.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean clicking at the document but NOT an element in it, 
have a look at stopPropegation()

Comment: The `document` is not something that has any physical extend on the page. You cannot just only capture a click on `document` because it is simply not possible to click on it -- or maybe I'm misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Added more code for more details, can you check it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this `stopPropagation` stuff is right, though this'll cause your script to throw errors on older versions of a certain browser. Guess which one? a cross-browser way:

```
$('#elem').click(function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;//IE doesn't pass the event object as standard to the handler
    //event would normally work, but if you declared some event variable in the current scope
    //all falls to pieces, so this e || window.event; thing is to be preferred (IMO)
    if (e.stopPropagation)//check if method exists
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    e.cancelBubble = true;//for IE
});
```

However, you wanted to check if the element that was actually clicked, is the one you need. The problem with that is, that the way the event is passed through the DOM. In W3C browsers the event is first passed to the document, and then clambers down to the element that was actually clicked (propagates through the dom). 
By contrast IE dispatches its events on the element itself, and then sends it up to the document (except for the `change` event triggered by select elements... to add insult to injury). What this effectively means is that a click event that is registered in to `body` element in W3C browsers might be on its way to a checkbox of sorts, or it could be a click inside an empty div. 
Again, in IE, when a click event reaches the `body` tag, it could have been dispatched too any element on the page. So it may prove useful in your case to google: `event delegation`, or turn to jQuery's `.delegate()` method.

Or check the event object to see if the event is allowed to propagate through or not:

```
var target =  e.target || e.srcElement;//target now holds a reference to the clicked element
```

The property names neatly show the difference between the bubbling model and the propagating one: in the first case (`srcElement`), the event is coming from a source element in the dom. In the W3C propagating model, the event is cought while it's headed for a `target` element somewhere in the dom. 
Look at it like a heat-seeking missile (w3c) versus a shower of debris after the target was shot down (IE, always the destructive one, and in this case often to late to respond to the events, and therefore to late to handle them:P)

Comment: Very interesting, +1 for the IE "fix"

Comment: it doesn't helped me, the element anyway reacts when i click on the document

Comment: @MisterPHP: I don't know what it is exactly you're trying to achieve here, but I think you'd be better off reading up on event handling and, especially, delegation. After that, and I'm sorry to put it this bluntly, I'd rethink my take on this if I were you. delegation is quite easy once you get the basic principle. Nowadays I have no more than 4 or 5 event listeners on an entire page, that can contain several forms, hundreds (literally) of selects and input elements, and they're all dealt with using delegation, and no more than 6~7 handlers. and no issues with events firing twice or more

Comment: @MisterPHP: I've seen the code you added now, you have to call the stopPropagation thingy @ the child's level, not on the parent. The handler of the child comes before the handler of the parent, that's where you'll have to stop the event. Also, since you're using jQuery: return false is an option, too (but read the docs, as it does a little bit more than just stopPropagation)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to check for the `event`'s `target`.

```
$('html').click(function(event){
    if (event.target != this){
    }else{
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZamqE/2/)

Comment: it doesn't helped me, the element anyway reacts when i click on the document

Comment: @MisterPHP, I've updated it. Now it's working, you can check the fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Elements on the document are part of the document, so if you click "some_element" in the document, it is obvious that event registered on document will be fired/triggered. If you dont want to execute code which was for "document" then first get the element OR "event source" which originates this event, and check if it was "some_element" in your question above.